# Close launched image/pdf file using Python code

Tags: python, file, python-2.7

I want to launch and close the image/pdf/word file while running my testcase in python. I am able to launch the image/pdf/word file successfully. But when I try to close the same file I am not able to do it. Does python supports closing the launched file?

MY REQUIREMENT IS, I HAVE TO SCAN THE IMAGE ON THE COMPUTER THROUGH CAMERA WHICH IS FIXED INFRONT OF THE COMPUTER FACING COMPUTER SCREEN WHEN MY TESTCASE IS RUNNING.

I can launch the file using following command :

```
import os
from os import path
os.system(path.join('C:\users\fakepath','image1.jpg'))
```

How to close launched file?

Comment: You're using the shell to open the file. It's kind of like putting your baby on a bus and then asking how to get it back

Comment: You ought to have searched this on the web, e.g. "opening and closing files in python" or something of that ilk. This is very basic! `open()` to open files and `f.close()` to close it. Or using `with, as:` blocks.

Comment: @2rs2ts My question may not be clear, but I will have to bring image which is hiding inside the folder to the top of the screen. So my desktop should open the file and show it on screen which I achieved through os.system(filename). once i am done i have to close it. for which I posted a question.

Comment: Ah. I think your problem is that [`os.system()` waits for the command process to exit](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system). I don't know how you've managed to execute a `.jpg` but your program is going to halt and wait for the command to finish executing so `os.system()` can return. Try using the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module. I'd code a solution for you, but, I'm not on Windows so I can't really test it.

Comment: And to answer the question "Does python support closing the launched file?": the answer is you didn't open the file with python, you launched an *application* which opened the file. It's that application's responsibility - baby, bus, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use subprocess instead:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen([path.join('C:\users\fakepath','image1.jpg')], shell=True)
...
#When you want the program to close
p.kill()
```

I would advise, however, that you call the program that you want to open the file directly instead of using shell=True. i.e.:

```
subprocess.Popen(['path_to_adobe_reader', 'path_to_pdf_file']...
```

Answer (score 6):

Using contexts is the preferred way:

```
with open('filename','r') as f:
    # do stuff with file


#here, f will automatically be closed.
```

Comment: I want to bring an image on top of the screen.. Not just reading the file... This won't work for me..